# What is the difference between axes and pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I am trying to embed matplotlib figure into PyQt4, but when I try to plot the figure using pyplot, it's giving an error or would make a separate matplotlib built-in figure object rather than plotting into my canvas.

If I try to plot using `axes`, all is good as figure gets plotted into the canvas. However, I can't plot two `axes` into a single graph which was done by `pyplot` by simply plotting two plots one after another.

So how can I 2 plots into one graph using `axes`?

```
class Foo(blah):
    """ some code here """

    # code which giving error:
    self.pyplot.plot_date(x,y)
    self.pyplot.plot_date(a,b)

    # code plotting matplotlib figure object rather drawing into canvas
    pyplot.plot_date(x,y)
    pyplot.plot_date(a,b)

    # code only plotting only a,b - but not x,y
    self.axes.plot_date(x,y)
    self.axes.plot_date(a,b)
```

Comment: Show what your put to x,y,a,b arrays. Does your dates array have intersection?

Comment: Never use `pyplot` if you are embedding Matplotlib in PyQt. The reason is that `pyplot` sets up its own gui, mainloop and canvas, which interfere with Qt. [This example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) shows how to do it correctly. I advise you try it and go from there. You can use `add_subplot` to create new axes on the figure.

Comment: Thanks @titusjan, yes I was actually using this example and realised there was a line of code which actually prevents plotting two dataseries on a single chart. So `self.axes.hold(False)` has been commented out!